# Way to iterate over all combinations of two variables with dynamic limit

Tags: python

I am looking for some numbers that meet a certain criteria. I would like to check every combination of two numbers within a specified limit, and when that limit is met, I would like to increase it, and check the combinations that I have not yet checked. I would like to do this without hashing/sets as there will be many combinations.

e.g. The following snippet will check every combination, and has a dynamic limit, but it will spend most of it's time checking values that were already checked.

```
limit = 1000

while True:
    for k in range(limit):
        for n in range(limit):
            if k**2 + 8*((2*k*n) + n**2 + (2*n) + (2*k) + 1) == ((k + n + 1)**2) + 7*((2*k*n) + n**2 + (2*n) + (2*k) + 1):
                pass # Do more checking not pertaining to this question
    limit += 1 # increase limit
```

This next snippet will be more efficient, but will miss values where k > n:

```
n = -1
while True:
    n += 1
    for k in range(n):
        if k**2 + 8*((2*k*n) + n**2 + (2*n) + (2*k) + 1) == ((k + n + 1)**2) + 7*((2*k*n) + n**2 + (2*n) + (2*k) + 1):
            pass # Do more checking not pertaining to this question
```

For some reason, I can't quite wrap my head around getting to every combination, and increasing the limit without repeating. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need cases where `k>n` though? As far as I understand if `(k, n)` satisfies your condition `(n, k)` will do too.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a set of perfect square numbers S1-S9 such that S1 + x = S2, S2 + x  = S3 ect. S1 = k^2 and S2 = (k + n +1)^2. so n is the number of squares between S1 and S2, and k defines S1, S1 = k^2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially, you are trying to iterate over all pairs of non-negative integers, out to infinity, without seeing any pair more than once. In particular, you want to generate all pairs `(k, n)` in increasing order of `max(k, n)`.

It's a good idea to separate the logic of generating the pairs from the logic of consuming them, by writing a generator function. There are, of course, infinitely many pairs, so it's up to you to stop iterating when you want to.

```py
def all_pairs():
    m = 0
    while True:
        for i in range(m):
            yield (i, m)
        for i in range(m + 1):
            yield (m, i)
        m += 1
```

Example usage:

```py
out = []

for k, n in all_pairs():
    out.append( (k, n) )
    if len(out) >= 25:
        break

print(out)
```

Output:

```py
[(0, 0), # m = 0
 (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), # m = 1
 (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), # m = 2
 (0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), # m = 3
 (0, 4), (1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 4), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4) # m = 4
]
```

Comment: I'm not sure if testing both `(3, 4)` and `(4, 3)` is beneficial. It might make sense to eliminate those in the generator.

Comment: The OP's code generates both, and the question explicitly says their second solution is more efficient *"but will miss values where k > n"*, so generating the pairs in both orders is the required behaviour. `k` and `n` are not symmetrical in the code they are used for.

Comment: Agreed, but the generator doesn't have to generate both. The comparison code can return/print both `k, n` and `n, k`, if `n != k`, when it finds a match.

Comment: Actually, I would like to generate both (3,4) and (4,3).

Comment: The generator's responsibility is to generate the pairs which the loop wants to iterate over. If the loop wants them in both orders then the generator should yield them in both orders.

Comment: I agree with you both, I am suggesting this as a performance optimisation. There is no point calculating the squares for both pairs. You can do it for one pair and simply reverse it if you find a match.

Comment: It's not a performance optimisation. The code checking for a match calculates `k**2 + 8*((2*k*n) + n**2 + (2*n) + (2*k) + 1)` which is not symmetric in `k` and `n`, so you have to calculate it both ways round however you slice it.

Comment: You may have missed that the `k**2` is outside the brackets, whereas `n**2` is inside the brackets so it is being multiplied by 8.

Answer (score 1):

(**EDITED**)

If I understood correctly, you want to cover increasingly large squares, e.g.:

```
# square of side 1
(0, 0) 
# square of side 2
(0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)
# square of side 3
(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 1), (2, 0)
# square of side 4
(0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3), (3, 2), (3, 1), (3, 0)
...
```

or, visually:

```
0 1 2 3
1 1 2 3
2 2 2 3
3 3 3 3
...
```

and the size of the square is the "limit".

If that is the case, what you could do is two consecutive loops:

```
max_limit = 3
limit = 0
i = j = 0
while limit < max_limit:
    i, j = 0, limit
    while i < limit:
        print((i, j), end=' ')
        # INSERT YOUR (I, J) CONDITION HERE
        i += 1
    while j >= 0:
        print((i, j), end=' ')
        # INSERT YOUR (I, J) CONDITION HERE
        j -= 1
    limit += 1
```

with output:

```
(0, 0) (0, 1) (1, 1) (1, 0) (0, 2) (1, 2) (2, 2) (2, 1) (2, 0)
```

Of course, this is not ideal because you now would have two different points where to execute essentially the same instructions (i.e. the `print()`).

Luckily, this can be easily rewritten as:

```
max_limit = 3
limit = 0
i = j = 0
while limit < 3:
    i, j = 0, limit
    countdown = limit * 2 + 1
    while countdown > 0:
        print((i, j), end=' ')
        # INSERT YOUR (I, J) CONDITION HERE
        if i < limit:
            i += 1
            countdown -= 1
        elif j >= 0:
            j -= 1
            countdown -= 1
    limit += 1
```

with the same output as before:

```
(0, 0) (0, 1) (1, 1) (1, 0) (0, 2) (1, 2) (2, 2) (2, 1) (2, 0)
```

This exploits the observation that the number of elements to generate at each `limit` level is given by `countdown = limit * 2 + 1`.

Comment: I am trying to increase the limit when the numbers k and n meet the limit, not when the two equations are equal, and I believe that this implementation will not produce pairs where k < n and n > than the original limit, i..e. (k = 0, n = 2000).

Comment: @Matt Perhaps, I understood. See the edits. Is that what you want?